# how use update query with sqlite plugin in cordova

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, phonegap-plugins

I triying to update a data pre-populate with cordova 5.1 and sqlite plugin, but it doesn't work. I read a lot of information but it doesn't work.

My datatype in sqlite are double, rows (a1,a2,a3) in table1

The database is opening good, I can see the data with a SELECT. but update I can't.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    function onDeviceReady(){
      var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "tables1.db", location: 'default', createFromLocation: 1});
}
```

examples doesn't work

1.-

```
    var a1= Math.cos(value1 * Math.PI / 180); 
    var a2= Math.cos(value2 * Math.PI / 180);
    var a3= Math.cos(value3 * Math.PI / 180);

var sqlTxt = "INSERT or replace INTO table1 (a1,a2,a3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql(sqlTxt,['a1','a2','a3'])}, errorCB, successCB);
```

2.-

```
var a1= Math.cos(value1 * Math.PI / 180); 
var a2= Math.cos(value2 * Math.PI / 180);
var a3= Math.cos(value3 * Math.PI / 180);

tx.executeSql('UPDATE table1 SET  a1 = '+a1+', a2 = '+a2+',a3 = '+a3+' ', [], queryDB, errorCB);
```

with no +

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE table1 SET  a1 = 'a1', a2 = 'a2',a3 = 'a3' ', [], queryDB, errorCB);
```

3.-

```
        var a1= Math.cos(value1 * Math.PI / 180); 
        var a2= Math.cos(value2 * Math.PI / 180);
        var a3= Math.cos(value3 * Math.PI / 180);     
tx.executeSql('UPDATE table1 SET  a1=?,a2=?,a3=?', ['a1','a2','a3'], queryDB, errorCB);
```

I don't know what is wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way of passing variable inside a sqlite query is incorrect here:

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE table1 SET  a1=?,a2=?,a3=?', ['a1','a2','a3'], queryDB, errorCB);
```

Which should be

```
tx.executeSql("UPDATE table1 SET  a1=?,a2=?,a3=?", [a1,a2,a3], queryDB, errorCB);
```

Make sure you get values in a1,a2,a3.